# What is 'it' in 'hold it' command?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Why you say 'Hold it.' what means 'Stop.'. What does 'it' means in this command?

Comment: The activity you were partaking in.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example conversation:

> "Then I turned left on Third Street and—"
>   "Hold it! I thought you couldn't turn left at that intersection?"

In this conversation, the imperative *hold it* is used to tell the other person to stop talking because there is a point of information that needs to be resolved before the conversation continues.

In this case, it's the turning left at a particular street that is being questioned. However, *hold it* is being applied to the entire conversation itself.

*Hold it* is also simply used to signify that the conversation should be stopped. Other expressions include:

> Just a minute.
>   Hang on.
>   Hold up.
>   Stop right there.
>   But, wait.

---

Of course, it doesn't need to apply to conversation.

I could walk in on a group of people having a pillow fight and shout "Hold it!" What I'm referring to is the pillow fight itself.

In general, unless using the phrase literally with respect to a physical object you've been asked to hold, it just means that the person you're telling to *hold it* should stop doing whatever it is that they're doing.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing my answer when yours came, and I couldn't simply discard it.

Answer (score 1):

The **it** in **hold it** indicates the doing that has to stop because of a certain reason.

It is an informal phrase that means, as you mentioned, wait or stop doing something. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold-it).

Example:

If you were preparing lunch, and suddenly, your father came to the kitchen and opened the fridge. You will understand right away that he wants to snack, so you may say:

> Hold it! The food will be ready very soon.

This means, in other words, stop what you are doing, which is opening the fridge to get something to eat, as the food will be on the table shortly.

If you were to say:

> Hold! The food will be ready very soon.

Then the question "hold what?" would immediately pop up in our heads since your "phrase" is incomplete.

**Stop** can also come with **it** and would mean the same thing as **hold it**, as mentioned [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stop-it-that).

However, in our example, it would be more fit without the **it** since the phrase "stop it" has an alarming sensation which is really not needed or necessary for the food issue here. So, we would say:

> Stop! The food will be ready very soon.

Now, would the question "Stop what?" comes to our minds?

The answer, of course, is no, because **stop** by itself indicates that you have to put the action you were doing to a pause state, when **hold**, by itself, doesn't.

Comment: Both answers complete each other. Thank you. It would be interesting to hear about - Hang on.
Hold up. In the same spirit

Comment: Glad I was able to help although I don't quite understand what do you mean by the _hang on_ and _hold up_ matter.

Comment: In previous answer Jason Bassford gave examples as Hang on, Hold up which mean the same. For not native speakers what sensation do you have when you hear such commands.

Comment: They have an attentive sensation, as such phrases get your attention when hearing them that you would shift your focus from the thing you were doing/saying to what the speaker is about to do/say.